# SymmetricDS registering the Client from Java Code

Tags: java, symmetricds

I'm using professional version of Symmetric DS(Symmetric DS pro 3.6.13).

We are able to add the client to the server but not able to register the client without manual click on “ALLOW” option .

We want to register the Client and open Connection from java code without manual intervention. Please Guide me for the same.

Error which is displays id:
[server] - RegistrationUriHandler - client:SLAVE2:? was not allowed to register.

Once we Click on “ALLOW” from GUI, Log shows:
[gui] - RegistrationService - Just opened registration for external id of SLAVE2 and a node group of client and a node id of SLAVE2
[gui] - f - Sending an initial load to SLAVE2

So, Please let me know how to configure the above steps from java Code(Not from GUI).

Client Java Code :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(new FileInputStream("D:/APS/DOP/Banking/SymmetricClient/src/client-SLAVE2_POSTGRES.properties"));
ClientSymmetricEngine symmetricEngine = new ClientSymmetricEngine(props);
symmetricEngine.openRegistration(props.getProperty("group.id"),props.getProperty("external.id"));
symmetricEngine.getRouterService().routeData(true);
symmetricEngine.getPullService().pullData(true);
symmetricEngine.getPushService().pushData(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the engine symmetricDs properties file on the server (similar to the file `D:/APS/DOP/Banking/SymmetricClient/src/client-SLAVE2_POSTGRES.properties`) and add these two lines:

```
auto.registration=true
auto.reload=true
```